# running a csf command from php not as root

Tags: php, bash, apache, centos

i am trying to run the following csf command from inside a php script:

```
$ipNbr = 199.231.184.25 ;   // for example
$csfCommand = 'sudo  /usr/sbin/csf  --tempdeny ' . $ipNbr . ' 3600;'  ;    
$csfResult = shell_exec($csfCommand) ;  

$csfResult = exec($csfCommand) ; // i also tried exec rather than shell_exec
```

so far this does not do anything at all, including returning any sort of error/diagnostic message.   inside my log file, i do see:

```
[Fri Nov 20 13:28:13 2015] [error] [client 66.201.41.254] sh: /usr/sbin/csf: Permission denied
```

i placed the following line inside of visudo:

```
visudo ;
marksdomain.com    ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/csf
```

i have tried every combination i can think of:

```
/bin/sudo  /usr/sbin/csf    . . . . 
sudo  /usr/sbin/csf     . . . . 
/usr/sbin/csf     . . . .
csf     . . . .
```

any ideas how i can fire off the csf command from inside the php script ??

thank you all very much.

Comment: Log in to command line and `su` as the same user that apache executes as, then run the same command. What happens?

Comment: EXCELLENT QUESTION (one i should have tried, thank you) - results:
sh: /usr/sbin/csf: Permission denied

Comment: Then you'll need to make sure you fix that issue.

Comment: again - excellent question - i did a couple of tweaks and was indeed able to do it from the command line logged in as that specific user, however i am still unable to do it from inside of apache.
Note too that i did a "whoami" just to verify that the usernames matched.

Comment: It would seem that one of your issues is that you attempt to execute as `sudo` but you don't have permissions to execute as sudo as the Apache user.

Answer (score 1):

i believe i have it working now, thanks entirely to all the kind and patient comments above:

```
$csfCommand = '/usr/bin/sudo  -u root  -s  /usr/sbin/csf  --tempdeny ' . $ipNbr . ' 3600;'
```

visudo:

```
marksDomain(dot)com   ALL=(ALL:ALL)   NOPASSWD:       /bin/sh
marksDomain(dot)com   ALL=(ALL:ALL)   NOPASSWD:       /usr/sbin/csf
```

Comment: Attempted to implement this and it worked great.  I've found however that since you're using sudo the '-u root -s' portion of $csfcommand is not needed.